# jQuery ATTR function with select/combo box

Tags: jquery, select, input, attr

I am trying to get the type of the form field on my form and it does not seem to work with combo box

the input works, but not the select and clearly it shows as "select-one"

[image: attr]

```
<select id="test">
    <option value=1>1</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="test2">

<hr>type of select:
<div id="a"></div>
<hr>type of input
<div id="b"></div>

var f = $('#test').attr('type');
$('#a').html(f);
var f = $('#test2').attr('type');
$('#b').html(f);​
```

Am i missing something? or it's a bug?

see: http://jsfiddle.net/TZjE5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to [**`.prop`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr`

```
var f = $('#test').prop('type');
$('#a').html(f);

type of select: select-one
```

Comment: so i should use prop for input as well?